# Does Android AutoUpdate Uninstall Before Install Of New Version?

Tags: android, auto-update

I am having some strange auto-update issues and cannot find an answer as to how it really works. My Android app creates several shared preferences and a cache file in the app directory.

When I put out an update to my app and is automatically is updated on user devices, does the update mechanism actually completely uninstall the old app, removing its shared preferences, cache file, and any other files the app created in the app directory? Or does it leave them intact?

I hope it actually does remove everything so that if I change something in my cache file design I do not have to programatically make sure the new app is not using the old cache file design.

I apologize if this has been asked/answered but could not find this info.

Answer (score 1):

The data stored in `/data/data/your.package.name/` will be kept during the update process.
Installing an update is basically the same as running `adb install -r myApp.apk` from the terminal.

In other words all your shared preferences and databases continue to exist after the update.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, no, Android does not remove files and preferences when upgrading an application. Otherwise you'd lose all your settings and data every time a developer updated their application.

(You're new to Android, right?)

Answer (score 1):

> I hope it actually does remove everything so that if I change
>   something in my cache file design I do not have to programmatically
>   make sure the new app is not using the old cache file design.

why? the purpose of update is to replace apk with new versions, users certainly would not like to loose their settings. What you should do is to version you cache, you can create share preference with current code cache version, and if you modify it in your code then in Application.onCreate you can check if version changed and delete cache if that is the case. You can also convert old cache format to new one.